# Why I am getting null value from method that asign value to global variable within try catch?

Tags: java, android

I am developing android apps using android studio, I have class like this,

```
public class validation_jemput{

String jenislayanan, jenispaket, tglmulai, address, latitude, longitude , note;

String status, detail;

public validation_jemput(String jenislayanan, String jenispaket, String tglmulai, String address, String latitude, String longitude , String note){
    this.jenislayanan=jenislayanan;
    this.jenispaket=jenispaket;
    this.tglmulai=tglmulai;
    this.address=address;
    this.latitude=latitude;
    this.longitude=longitude;
    this.note=note;
}

public void validate_jemput(){
    RequestParams params2 = new RequestParams();
    params2.put("order[jenislayanan]", jenislayanan);
    params2.put("order[jenispaket]", jenispaket);
    params2.put("order[tglmulai]", tglmulai);
    params2.put("destinasi[0][address]", address);
    params2.put("destinasi[0][latitude]", latitude);
    params2.put("destinasi[0][longitude]", longitude);
    params2.put("destinasi[0][note]", "");
    Request.post_with_auth("api/validationjemput", params2, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("status");
                JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
                String tempstatus = collegeData.getString("status");
                String tempdetail = collegeData.getString("detail");
                status = tempstatus;
                detail = tempdetail;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    });
}
public String get_detail(){
    return this.detail;
}
}
```

And then, I called method get_detail() from my activity and I am getting null value. What's wrong? please help me.. And then, I called method get_detail() from my activity and I am getting null value. What's wrong? please help me thank you

Comment: Silly question, but are you waiting for the post to respond before you call get_detail() ? Seems likely to me you're not?

Answer (score 0):

try to confirm if your tempdetail variable was assigned a value

```
String tempdetail = collegeData.getString("detail");
```